# Direct link to Facebook mobile site using pageID

Tags: facebook

graph.facebook.com/cocacola will tell you that the id for the cocacola page is 40796308305.

You can get to the cocacola page using either www.facebook.com/cocacola or www.facebook.com/40796308305.

However, to get to the mobile facebook site m.facebook.com/cocacola works, m.facebook.com/40796308305 doesn't.

For reasons I won't go into I have the pageID, not the vanity url and I need to link to the mobile site.

Specifically, I'd like to link to the equivalent of m.facebook.com/cocacola?v=feed to link to the wall instead of info.

So, I either need a way to link to a mobile page using the page id or a way to make the regular www link redirect to the mobile wall instead of the info page.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to create (or discover the already created) proper "name" ID and use that together with the pageID as your landing page, for example, mine works as follows:
http://m.facebook.com/pages/BCmoney-MobileTV/190267987672979

But using just my pageID it does not:
http://m.facebook.com/pages/190267987672979

In addition, you could use the Graph API to deduce the "vanity URL" as you refer to it:
http://graph.facebook.com/40796308305

Looks like this is the page you're looking for:
http://m.facebook.com/pages/Coca-Cola/40796308305

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I found to get the mobile version of any Facebook page is to go the desktop version of the page on your browser of choice and then replace the `www` with `m` and press `Enter`. The Facebook Mobile Web version of the page loads in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a link on a website, but I don't want everyone to go to the mobile site, just those on mobile devices.

The solution was to add `?v=wall` to it.  It works for both desktop and mobile now.  Here is what my link looks like now:  https://www.facebook.com/pages/Virginia-B-Andes-Volunteer-Community-Clinic/153180528039538?v=wall